# Arduino Ethernet Access-Control-Allow-Origin issues

Tags: c++, ajax, arduino, cors, access-control

Hey all i am trying to **post** data to the arduino ethernet microprocesser but it seems to not work when i try to call the function within my app using Jquery AJAX.

Here is the ajax code:

```
function sendToArduinoEthernet(whatsBeingSent) {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        async : true,
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        url: "http://192.168.9.199:199/?r=" + whatsBeingSent,
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "text/html",
        dataType: "html",
        success: OnSuccessCallArduino,
        error: OnErrorCallArduino
    });      
}
```

And this is the Arduino code:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

boolean reading = false;
char c;
EthernetClient client;
String readString = String(30); //string for fetching data from address

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Ethernet CONFIGURE
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 9, 199 };   //Manual setup only 421
  byte gateway[] = { 192, 168, 9, 1 }; //Manual setup only
  byte subnet[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 }; //Manual setup only
  byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; // if need to change the MAC address (Very Rare)
  EthernetServer server = EthernetServer(199); //port 199
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//CONFIGURE for relays
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //(analog->digital output)
  int relay1 = 14; //Android phone USB power (turn on to shut off power to phone)
  int relay2 = 15; //Bluray eject
  int relay3 = 16; //PC power button
  int relay4 = 17; //Android Phone Power button

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(relay3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(relay4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(fan1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(fan2, OUTPUT);

    analogWrite(fan1, pwmVal);
    analogWrite(fan2, pwmVal);
    digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(relay3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(relay4, HIGH);

    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet); //for manual setup  
    server.begin();
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop(){
    checkForClient();
}

void checkForClient(){
    client = server.available();

    if (client) {
      boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
      boolean sentHeader = false;

      while (client.connected()) {
          if (client.available()) {  
              if(!sentHeader){
                // send a standard http response header
                client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                sentHeader = true;
              }

              c = client.read();

              if (readString.length() < 16)
              {
                readString += String(c);
              }

              if(reading && c == ' ') reading = false;
              if(c == '?') reading = true; //found the ?, begin reading the info 
              if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) break;

              if (c == '\n') {
                currentLineIsBlank = true;          
              }else if (c != '\r') {
                currentLineIsBlank = false;
              }
          }
      }  
      delay(1);   
      switchStuff(readString);
      client.stop();
      readString = "";
      c = ' ';
      reading = false;
    }
}

void switchStuff(String stuff) {
  stuff.toLowerCase();
  //client.println(stuff);

  if (stuff.indexOf("r1on") > 0) {    
    digitalWrite(relay1, LOW); //Turn 5v USB power ON
  } else if (stuff.indexOf("r1off") > 0) {
    digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH); //Turn 5v USB power OFF
  } else if (stuff.indexOf("r2") > 0) {
    digitalWrite(relay2, LOW); //Eject bluray Disc
    delay(500); //pause for 1/2 second
    digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
  } else if (stuff.indexOf("r3") > 0) {
    digitalWrite(relay3, LOW); //"Push" the pc power button
    delay(500); //pause for 1/2 second
    digitalWrite(relay3, HIGH); //"Release" the pc power button
  } else if (stuff.indexOf("r4") > 0) {
    digitalWrite(relay4, LOW); //"Push" phone power button down
    delay(7000); //pause for 7 seconds
    digitalWrite(relay4, HIGH); //"Relese" phone power button
  } else if (stuff.indexOf("r5") > 0) {
    digitalWrite(relay4, LOW); //"Push" phone power button down
    delay(500); //pause for 1/2 second
    digitalWrite(relay4, HIGH); //"Relese" phone power button
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header must be sent by the HTTP server.

The [`Cross-Origin Resource Sharing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) is a security feature embedded in every recent web browser which defines a way in which the browser and the server can interact to determine whether or not to allow the cross-origin request.

The access to the resources exposed by your server is dictated by the `CORS` policy he defines in its response to your request. So, you might want to return this header server-side rather than using it in your request client-side. Failing to do so will lead to an error throwed by your browser stating that you have no right to access the given resource.

You'll find further details and a straight-forward example of this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Simplified_example).

Comment: The header is not part of the HTML document returned by the Arduino. What you need to do, is sending back the appropriate header (typically  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` if you'd like to allow cross domain access to the resources you expose using every HTTP verb) with the HTTP response you sent back to the client.

Comment: I guess that this could be achieved by adding something similar to `client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")` to your given code.